# How to create own datepicker control in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to create my own datepickar control(or dll),so can use it another project.How to create that?

Comment: Given what you're asking for, it is far too little text for anyone to reply. Have you tried searching for an answer to this for yourself?

Answer (score 1):

Why create such a thing for yourself and invest a lot of time investigating, fixing problems, providing support, ... for it?

There are a bunch of such controls available which can be found with a simple search via your preferred search engine.

For ASP.NET I would suggest to either buy a 3rd party control from a well known vendor or take a look at the following:

- [jQuery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)
- [ASP.NET Ajax Control Toolkit Calendar control](https://ajaxcontroltoolkit.codeplex.com/documentation)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using ASP.NET 4.0 or above, I'd suggest using the Bootstrap datepicker to keep your application looking consistent.

You can find the Bootstrap datepicker here: https://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/